# Child Portal creation in Django CMS

Tags: python, django, django-cms

How can we create child portals in django-cms, & how can we manage the access permissions of these child portals?

I have a main website like "www.example.com" which have its own url structure & pages. Also I have several departments/regions in it like east/west/north/south. These regions contains their own content apart from the main site.

So main website can be treated as parent & these regions can be treated as child portals. Child portals url should be like "www.example.com/portal1/home". Child portals need to have their own admins & permissions.

Comment: What do you mean by 'portal'? What specific problem do you have with django-cms?

Comment: @markwalker_ I have edited the question.

Comment: Just create pages for departments/regions & then give them their content in sub pages. Their top level pages could be excluded from the navigation to keep them separate from the main 'website' or included through a 'regions' page so that they were easily found. Basically you need to play with the page tree, then learn how menus work do do what you want.